# C# logging percentage progress every n'th

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, progress-bar, percentage

I'm downloading/uploading file, and I need to log the progress of that, right now I'm logging percentage of that progress, but my problem is that it prints too many lines, it can take up to 100+ lines just of 0.04%.. 0.06% etc.
What I need is to log every 5% percent of progress, so it would be 0% 5% 10% 15% ... 95% 100%.

```
public async Task Send(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] fileBytes, CancellationToken ct)
{
            var offset = 0;
            var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(fileBytes);
            while (true)
            {
                var segment = buffer.GetSegment(offset, 1024);
                offset += segment.Count;

                var packet = new DataTransferPacket(segment).Serialize(ctx.Allocator.Buffer());
                await ctx.WriteAndFlushAsync(packet);

                var progress = Math.Round((double) offset / fileBytes.Length * 100);

                if (progress % 5 == 0)
                { 
                    var byteProgress =
                    $"[{offset.ToString().PadLeft(fileBytes.Length.ToString().Length)} / {fileBytes.Length} Bytes]";
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Uploading {progress,6:0.00}% {byteProgress,12}");
                }

                await Task.Delay(100, ct);
                if (offset == fileBytes.Length)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
}
```

So far I couldn't find solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just track which percentage is the next "step" you want to log:

```
public async Task Send(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] fileBytes, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var offset = 0;
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(fileBytes);
    var nextLogThresh = 0; // <== new line
    while (true)
    {
        var segment = buffer.GetSegment(offset, 1024);
        offset += segment.Count;

        var packet = new DataTransferPacket(segment).Serialize(ctx.Allocator.Buffer());
        await ctx.WriteAndFlushAsync(packet);

        var progress = Math.Round((double) offset / fileBytes.Length * 100);

        if (progress >= nextLogThresh) // <== new line
        { 
            var byteProgress =
            $"[{offset.ToString().PadLeft(fileBytes.Length.ToString().Length)} / {fileBytes.Length} Bytes]";
            _logger.LogInformation($"Uploading {progress,6:0.00}% {byteProgress,12}");
            nextLogThresh += 5; // <== new line
        }

        await Task.Delay(100, ct);
        if (offset == fileBytes.Length)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This won't log the last "100%" of course, so if you want that you'd need to add an extra `_logger.LogInformation(...)` inside the `if (offset == fileBytes.Length)`